# Best practice for EF navigation properties in WCF

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, entity-framework

What would be the suggested pattern and/or technology for accomplishing the following based on current status of .NET?

I want to propagate my EF-generated model of a SQL database through WCF services. I wan't to switch off Lazy Loading in EF because I don't want the cascading load of the hierarchical structured entities.

On the Client-Side I wan't to be able to access navigation-properties as if I would deal with real EF-objects and not with the WCF-proxies. I don't want to send the EF-objects including context-objects because this would destroy the SOA-pattern in my opinion.

In fact I want to change the implementation of the Reference.cs-files generated by Visual Studio so that each access to a navigation-property will raise an asyncronous callback to the service-layer if needed.

Sample: This is a Company-class which is referencing a mandatory through a navigation property. This is what default WCF-proxy-technique is giving me:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public AddressManager.CompanyService.Mandatory Mandatory {
        get {
            return this.MandatoryField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.MandatoryField, value) != true)) {
                this.MandatoryField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Mandatory");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is what I want it to be:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public AddressManager.CompanyService.Mandatory Mandatory {
        get {
            if (this.MandatoryField == null)
            {
                // RAISE SERVICE-METHOD HERE
            }
            return this.MandatoryField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.MandatoryField, value) != true)) {
                this.MandatoryField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Mandatory");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider using WCF Data Services for this pattern.

Comment: @JeffN825: Thanks alot. I thought to complicated ;-). Tested it out and it is the right thing for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a good way.

- You are talking about SOA and in the same time you are going to violate one of former SOA tenets - Boundaries are explicit. That means that you should not hide any remote call into property getter. Explicit means that developer must see that if he wants additional data he must call method on the proxy and it will create remote call which is 1000x times slower then local call. No hidden remote calls in property getters. What you designed is actually lazy loading over WCF and that is something you should avoid.
- One of the main targets in most distributed systems is reducing roundtrips so creating roundtrip for each navigation property can be bad approach. If you are creating client code which will need multiple related entities loaded the best way is special service operation which will return all of them in single roundtrip. Multiple roundtrips make sense only if loading related entities happens later during another client operation which is not related to the operation where initial entity was loaded.
- Do not touch Reference.cs - that is generated code and generated code should not be never manually modified because once you do any single change on your service and update proxy your modification will be lost.

Comment: Thanks. I was blind because I didn't thought that OData would be the right thing for me. To go into your suggestions: Isn't it very bad stuff to load a hole bunch of data which I potentially don't want to use? This cascading behavior is something we want to avoid in most circumstances!

Comment: You should load only data you want to use but if you know that you will need additional data you should include them in that call. If you don't know it you should provide explicit methods for loading them - you will do exactly the same with data services. No hidden magic.

Comment: I agree with you. The problem is, that there are so many good new techniques accomplishing this in terms of generating the code for us that I just thought that I'm wrong in using it the way WCF supports. In most business-projects there are people who work on a veery low skill-level or they have skills but no time to use them. Anyway: In many cases I need a technology which hides this complexity from the devoloper. I don't like it but need it (*Ashamed_at_moment_ of_writing*). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff told me to use OData and it worked for me. Thanks!